# What changes to specific Witch Doctor skills can I make through equipment?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

Before the game was released, data miners were speculating that each class would have a list of certain modifiers available on equipment that would provide small changes to the way class skills would work (e.g. "reduce cool down of wall of zombies by 2 seconds").

Have the existence of these modifiers on items been confirmed, and is there a list of what ability modifiers are available for Witch Doctor skills?

Are there restrictions on what types of equipment they may appear on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [DiabloFans' list](http://www.diablofans.com/topic/41045-spoiler-diablo-iii-item-affixes/#entry863957) from the Bradygames Strategy guide:

> Firebats - Reduced Mana Cost
>
> Haunt - Boosted Damage
>
> Poison Darts - Boosted Damage
>
> Spirit Barrage - Boosted Damage
>
> Plague of Toads - Boosted Damage
>
> Corpsespiders -??? (Transcribed improperly)
>
> Locust Swarm - +% crit chance
>
> Firebomb - Reduced Mana Cost
>
> Zombie Charger - Reduced Mana Cost
>
> Wall of Zombies - Reduced Cooldown Time
>
> Acid Cloud - +% crit chance
>
> Summon Zombie Dogs - Reduced Cooldown Time.

Exact magnitude varies with level and the exact item. Most of these show up on Voodoomasks / Dolls / Ceremonial knives, but they can appear on regular helms, offhands, and weapons as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually get a look at this by searching in the Auction House, as each skill modifier shows up as an individual search. Here's what I was able to find, along with the visible ranges for each effect (it's very likely that these aren't the caps, just that higher ones aren't posted):

One handed and two handed weapons:

- Reduces resource cost of Firebomb by X mana. (AH shows a range between 1 and 7.)
- Increases Haunt damage by X%. (AH shows a range between 5 and 9%.)
- Increases Plague of Toads damage by X%. (AH shows a range between 5 and 11%.)

Off-hands and two handed weapons:

- Increases Poison Dart damage by X%. (AH shows a range between 5 and 11%.)
- Increases Spirit Barrage damage by X%. (AH shows a range between 5 and 10%.)
- Reduces cooldown of Wall of Zombies by X seconds. (AH shows a range between 1 and 3.)
- Reduces resource cost of Zombie Charger by X mana. (AH shows a range between 3 and 9.)

Armor:

- Increases Critical Hit Chance of Acid Cloud by X%. (AH shows a range between 1 and 6%.)
- Reduces resource cost of Firebats by X mana. (AH shows a range between 1 and 9.)
- Reduces cooldown of Zombie Dogs by X seconds. (AH shows a range between 1 and 6.)